# How can I draft multiple posts?

Tags: support, feature-request, asking-questions, draft

I need to keep drafts of multiple questions before posting them on Stack Overflow, so I can post them or discard them accordingly later after doing the required additions/corrections and research.

Kindly implement this feature if it seems helpful for many.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts (the request is not yet rejected... but no status at all, anyway)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The site only keeps one draft question. There is no feature to save more than one.

The workaround is simple though: use your favorite text editor to save your drafts, just like you would for anything else. If you would like to have that always available, use an online application to do it (something like Google Docs for instance). There are even services out there that handle Markdown (like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) for instance) and can synchronize with other online services for storage.

Adding a feature to save multiple drafts seems like a lot of work for something that is rather trivial to do yourself.