# Preparing more than one question simultaneosly

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, draft

Currently, SO supports and stores only a single current question.  If I try to prepare another question, I get the other question's saved state instead.

So I suggest that it is possible to prepare and save more than one question simultaneously.

Comment: The only use case I can think of for this is if you want to post them simultaneously. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: @BoltClock: Preparation of my questions does take time.

Comment: You could also prepare them elsewhere (like locally, on your computer). Or just keep bouncing back and forth between copies, testing them in the Stack Overflow preview. I can't see this being a huge obstacle to overcome, honestly.

Comment: Having multiple drafts has been asked before on the old MSO and now live on MSE: [List all my drafts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts)

Comment: @psubsee2003: So is it OK to create a sandbox on SO, too?

Comment: @false there's nothing wrong with asking for the same feature here, I was just pointing it out that it was asked before.

Comment: related: [How can I draft multiple questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251432/839601)

Comment: I'm echoing Kevin , though it admittedly would be *nice* to have a save feature... it adds some bloat to the site itself. Probably, a fraction of users would use the feature anyway...

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion being able to save multiple questions at once could be useful on occasion.

However, that is also part of the problem with this feature request. It wouldn't be used very often, if at all by some users. It would also require a decent footprint of code to implement (some sort of draft management system).

The ratio of time for the team to implement versus amount of impact to users is too small to be viable I believe. While it is a nice idea, it just doesn't seem like a priority as a result of only applying to a small audience when compared to other features in the works.