# Can I write a private/draft question?

Tags: support, feature-request

I would like to create a "draft" or "private" question and publish it for the public when I feel it ready.

Am I able to do that on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. Like Paulo, I do not know how to write **one** draft, except from having it in my notepad or so.

Comment: Re-posted + answered:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319564/can-i-write-a-private-draft-question-or-answer

Comment: Yes you can
-----------

Actually you can have **one** draft question or answer. You just start working on your text or code. Then you can move to another page, but your edit stays saved, so that if you return to questions, then it is still there.

Having more than one was rejected by the community: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251432/how-can-i-draft-multiple-questions ; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts