# How can I save and retrieve drafts of multiple unpublished posts?

Tags: support, draft

I click "Ask" and make a draft of an unpublished post, and its draft is automatically saved, even if I close the web browser tab. The next time I click "Ask", I will get back the draft of the post.

If I click "Ask" again, ignore the draft of the previous post, and make a draft of a second post. Then the draft of the second post is  automatically saved, and I can't get back the content of the first draft.

- Is it possible to retrieve the draft of the first post?
- Is it possible to save the draft for the first post, before making the draft for the second post? That is, is it possible to save drafts of more than one posts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the draft of the first post?

No, there is per user only one draft saved for a question and one for an answer on the server. In all cases, last saved draft wins.

> Is it possible to save the draft for the first post, before making the draft for the second post? That is, is it possible to save drafts of more than one posts?

No, it is not possible to save drafts for more than one question or answer.
Your only option, hack if you like, is to post the draft and immediately delete it. Users under 10K can then find those deleted posts in their profile under *deleted recent answers* (or questions) for 60 days. Users with 10K or more can search for their own deleted posts.

See also [List all my drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts) and [How can I draft multiple questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251432/how-can-i-draft-multiple-questions?rq=1)