# Save drafts across devices

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, draft

When I create a draft in a desktop browser I sometimes would like to continue to work on it in the iOS (or Android) app or vice versa.

Please allow me to sync the draft(s) I made in one place over to the other place. Let me switch devices any way and and any time I want.

**Update2:** Since you already save the draft I made in the browser on the server and sync works between browsers, why not go the extra mile a make this sync with the mobile apps too?

**Update1:** Here is an example concrete use case, because you asked for it in the comments:

For example I starteted to formulate a question (or an answer) at my PC at work but did not have time to finish it. I would like to do that when I am commuting or when I am at Starbucks and only have my iPad around or when I am back home where have my iMac.

Comment: hmm.  Right now the draft is saved on the client side.  To do what you ask would mean they would need to be saved server side.  Not sure if SO cares or not but that would allow people to share a login and communicate through a hidden draft.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251433/4826457) to a _different question_ suggests using third party services like stackedit...

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see how that should matter. If they want to, just let them. They can probably already do that now (e.g. though Private information in the profile). If there this is a storage size concern, just introduce a limit.

Comment: If you're limited to one draft (as you are now), the limit is already sort of built in to that.

Comment: That limit does not exist in the apps though.

Comment: You mean like Dropbox?  Already exists..

Comment: @MartinJames No, I deliberatly do *not* mean "like Dropbox". Resorting to Dropbox for this would result in an absolutely horrible user experience, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: You can use AirDrop between iOS/macOS devices to transfer pieces of text by a simple drag&drop.

Comment: *"sometimes would like to continue"* - sounds like a bad habit to me. You didn't explain the reasons what would make this feature request important. Copy/paste using usb-stick, send drafts via email, etc.

Comment: @Sinatr In times of heterogenous devices, where "continuos clients" should be the default way of thinking this seems so obvious to me.I have updated my question.

Comment: Synchronizing = no. A comfortable way to store/restore draft = better, this will not swarm server side with thousands of drafts.

Comment: @bitbonk: That would be something to handle client-side. The idea of "continuous clients" is that the website doesn't need to be able to tell you've switched devices. Tabs, cookies, local storage, cache etc would have to be synced by the browsers. Not by the site.

Comment: @Cerebrus As a user I do not care about all of this. Just remove the friction and enable the above use case.

Comment: @Sinatr The Stackexchange network has generated literally billions of questions and answers, I'd be suprised if they couldn't handle one or two more texts per user at relatively low cost.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hidden draft could actually be a useful thing on SO, also considering the mentoring idea, hence mentors could access and edit to improve before they are posted, hence they could get 2 fly's in one...

Comment: @bitbonk Just gotta say, the "they've done so much, so they can handle a little more" mentality is not a very good way to manage a website. SE has been able to generate so many questions and answers because they spend inordinate amounts of time reducing the cost of every operation to the bare minimum. I'm deliberately not taking a stance on whether this operation is worth the cost, but I will take a stance that this line of reasoning is not sound.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I totally agree. Depending on the value this feature would add for the users, they would have to asses the cost.

Comment: I, for one user, actively do not want that feature to be implemented. I literally do not care about it.

Comment: Maybe this feature exists (or is planned) in some browsers, or as an add-on? Chrome will re-open the tabs you had open on another device if you want it to, so having unsubmitted form entries transferred isn't a huge leap.

Comment: _"Just remove the friction and enable the above use case."_: Didn't you read my comment? It's the browser / OS's job to remove that friction. Not the site's job. Look at what @m69 said. That's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Can we please not think for the Stack Overflow maintainers? Saving a million drafts of a couple of paragraphs will take a few MBs in a database. That doesnt "swarm server side", the server won't even notice.

Comment: Looks like there is a browser extension you can use. Check this out https://superuser.com/questions/1182283/share-the-browser-session-cookies-local-storage-between-computers

Comment: @jontro As mentioned above, it already works in the browser. Just not between the apps and the apps and the browser.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the draft post is not made available via the [API that the apps use](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Probably they could have a `questions/{id}/answers/draft` command to fetch any drafts the authenticated user might have saved.

Comment: @CodeCaster "Saving a million drafts of a couple of paragraphs will take a few MBs in a database" - only if a couple of paragraphs = a few bytes - so those sort of answers will probably get closed as VLQ!  ;)  (But I agree that it will be small storage requirement compared to the total being used.)