# Is there any way to "draft" questions on-site and show them to specific people, but not publicly?

Tags: support, asking-questions, self-answer, canonical, draft

I am the room owner for the [Python canon discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion) chat room, where I have been trying to sort out a variety of issues related to important canonical questions in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. (I also use it to report progress on tasks such as identifying the best canonical version of a question, editing those for clarity and style, cross-referencing them, and especially fixing old duplicate links so that everything routes directly to the best version of the question.)

In our room discussion (admittedly it is still *mostly* me talking to myself) it often comes up that a canonical question seems to be entirely lacking: every existing version of a question seems to flail around and not quite hit the *actual* question that would be most useful in an encyclopedic Q&A format. So I'll try to figure out a really good title and a basic idea for what that question should contain, and hopefully then get around to drafting an actual question and my own best answer to it.

Thus far, however, my drafting has generally been off-site: either on my own hard drive using a Markdown editor, or pushed [to my corresponding GitHub repository](https://github.com/zahlman/so-workshop/) (which I've been neglecting...).

**Is there any way that I can do the drafting on site instead?** I would like to be able to share a link to the chatroom, so that people with the link can review what I have in mind before I expose them to the public. The issue is that, because these questions tend to address relatively fundamental (and thus "easy") material, and since they sometimes need to be fairly comprehensive, they are likely to attract downvotes without extensive editing, and in my experience those downvotes are *often* not revoked after the issues are resolved.

I want to stress here that I **do not care about my account's reputation score, but** such downvoting lowers the visibility of questions - permanently! - that I imagine to be of top importance to the goal of improving the site. That is to say: in the short term, people see the question (because it's on the Active tab) and add more downvotes; later, they'll forget about it and it will fall way, way down in the listings in general. *I want the opposite*: it should have relatively low visibility initially, and higher visibility once it's fixed - based on feedback from trusted individuals who *specifically understand what I am trying to accomplish* with the question.

I should also mention: I specifically want to **avoid getting [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) answers** while the question is still in a "draft" state, since I may have inadvertently come across as an actual beginner looking for help, and there are many people around who will offer that help regardless of how contrary it is to the site goals. I can also imagine a circumstance in which I intend to write my own answer to the question, but I want to finalize the question first, or just take a break (because it's hard work!).

Comment: No. Related [How can I draft multiple posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251432/1595451)ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: This work is very much commendable, especially with the current level of duplication, noise of various kinds, and search engine failures.

Comment: What about if you post a question on Meta to ask for help on writing a specific question?. Depending on the [tag:python] community it might require specific workings / wording (I don't know if they like/prefer "FAQ", "canonical", "refererence" or "community wiki" terms).

Comment: @Makoto I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is about sharing drafts publicly, but the other question is about having multiple private drafts.

Comment: @DonaldDuck:  I triple checked and the solution is similar.  In both cases - wanting to have drafts - the site is limited in its power to do so, and the recommendation in both cases is to use a tool like StackEdit.  The visibility in either case is irrelevant since you could just never share the link to your StackEdit instance.

Comment: @Makoto I agree with Donald Duck. I don't think that the only solution is to use a tool like StackEdit.

Comment: Historically related, though may not help in this case: [Mentorship Research Project - Results + Wrap-Up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357198/2821954) (draft + chat room)

Comment: This sounds 90% like the staging ground. Wondering if it would be suitable for this…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You'll have to use an off-site Markdown editing tool, perhaps something like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) (no affiliation).

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you *can* **draft** questions with "limited" visibility... if you accept that "limited" will mean just you. What I mean is: when you type a question in the /ask page and wait a few moments, you'll see "Draft saved" in green below the editor. You can type your full question on the /ask page and then take a screenshot of it to share with your colleagues. This will allow you to show users the question you want to ask *as it would appear on the site*, without *actually* posting it. Just remember to discard the question draft when you're done.

If you type in a title in the title field, the page will show suggested existing questions between the title field and your post body, making it difficult to capture a full screenshot including both the title and the tags, but you could include the title at the top of your body in `### Title` format.

Example:

[image: Screenshot of the /ask page with a sample question, including the tags input field below]

The potential downside is, if you were hoping for your colleagues to be able to interact with the question themselves (e.g. edits or answers), this won't be possible.

One *small* upside is that, since this is a draft, you can add more than five tags. This could be useful if you are not sure which tags you need to pick from and want to list all tag candidates and have folks discuss which ones are most appropriate for a given question (since visual aids often help):

[image: screenshot of more than 5 tags in the question editor page, inspired by Toni Basil]

Comment: The core of this questions is to share drafts, but this part was not addressed.

Comment: @Rubén You can share a link to an image just as easily as a link to any other web resource, like a Stack Overflow question. In fact, a link posted in chat is arguably _better_ because it will auto-onebox and users won't have to click through to start reading the content.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have be more specific. It doesn't look that the OP's goal is to show how the question looks in SO, but they are looking to have the edit/wiki features + collaboration before publishing a question on the main site.

Comment: @Rubén OK, I disagree; Karl doesn't say anywhere in his question that he is wanting others to have the ability to edit the draft post, only that they are able to 'review' the post... which requires 'view' access only.

Comment: Well, I only had viewing in mind when I asked, because I didn't dare dream that big. Being able to edit would be *better*, I suppose, but that's where Stack Overflow support questions end and blue-sky redesign begins.